# Should somebody telling you that they are a policeman ring any alarm bells when money is concerned?

Tags: scams

My partner is selling her car and one of the offers she had was from someone claiming to be a policeman.  My partner did not ask him what he did for a living, it was definitely volunteered information.

This got me to wonder: in a context where you have a one-off important transaction - like buying/selling a car, is there an elevated tendency for scammers to claim positions of trust, say police or the like?

Whatever other measures you'd take to protect yourself, there is no easy, foolproof, way to check that the person is indeed a policeman.  But, if you were a scammer would be a good way to reassure someone that you can be trusted - you can always bail out if you are pressed too much for corroborating details.

The deal didn't go through and of course, the person could really have been a policeman.  I am **not** asking for advice or about the likelihood of this being true in *this particular case*.  Only if claiming positions of trust like this is a tactic that scammers tend to use.

Comment: It seems possible that the intention was that "_I'm a policeman_" (whether true or not) contains an implied "_so don't try to scam **me**_".

Comment: @TripeHound Entirely possible.  We won't know for a fact.  I almost think it would be worth posting as an answer - there is a real cost to having excessive distrust societally and yours is a good reminder of possible positive motives.  But I am not familiar enough with this site to know what the community would think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "con" in con-artist stands for "confidence". It comes from the term "[confidence game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_trick)", which is what many internet scams are.

So yes, volunteering information that may make the scammer appear more trustworthy and believable is most definitely part of the playbook. Scammers impersonate law enforcement in a whole variety of different scam scenarios, all intended to instill fear and try to convince the mark that the law enforcement is after them and there's a risk in going to law enforcement themselves.

In the case of the potential sale, it may be that the potential purchaser was in fact a policeman. However volunteering this information without being asked should probably raise flags whether it is true or not. The likely end game would be to threaten the seller/mark not to complain about underpayment or non-payment under one pretext or another, or to pressure/guilt into lower sales price under the pretext of "supporting the troops".

In most jurisdictions, law enforcement are legally prohibited from using their authority and power for personal gain, so a *real* and *honest* policeman wouldn't try to gain confidence by flashing their badge.